# Native Base double press button to trigger function react native

Tags: function, react-native, button, double-click, native-base

I'm trying to trigger function onPress{() => someFunction()} but I need to tap twice in order to trigger function. Can anybody help me in this case? I'm using Native Base Framework for UI components in react native. Is this a bug?

Comment: Please provide a code base, it will help others to check the issue

Comment: You must share code snippet

Answer (score 0):

On press method could be like this:

```
onPressFunction () {
    if (this.state.wasPressedOnce) {
        // do here what you want to do in double press <---
    } else {
      this.setState({ wasPressedOnce: true });
      setTimeout(
          () => {
              this.setState({ wasPressedOnce: false });
          }, 1000); // 1000 is the time the user have to double press the button
    }
}
```

This basically calculate when you press the button if the button was pressed before the last 1 second.